# I want to show alert message

Tags: javascript

This is running good, but i want to show alert message if sum of all input value not equal to hundred and stop on same page.

```js
function doMath(){
  // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
  var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
  var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
  var my_input3 = document.getElementById('my_input3').value;
  var my_input4= document.getElementById('my_input4').value;
  var my_input5 = document.getElementById('my_input5').value;
  var my_input6 = document.getElementById('my_input6').value;
            
  // Add them together and display
  var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2) + parseInt(my_input3) + parseInt(my_input4) + parseInt(my_input5) + parseInt(my_input6);
  document.write(sum);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input1" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input2" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input3" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input4" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input5" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input6" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
```

Comment: alert('Hi!, good coding');

Comment: test your value [If else](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)  then use [Alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)

Comment: You might want to avoid using `document.write` [after the page has finished loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: But let me know how can i check all value is equl two hundred then show alert message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is another solution

```js
function _get(ID){
  return document.getElementById(ID);
}

function doMath(){
  var my_input1 = _get('my_input1').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input1').value) : 0;
  var my_input2 = _get('my_input2').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input2').value) : 0;
  var my_input3 = _get('my_input3').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input3').value) : 0;
  var my_input4 = _get('my_input4').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input4').value) : 0;
  var my_input5 = _get('my_input5').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input5').value) : 0;
  var my_input6 = _get('my_input6').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input6').value) : 0;
            
  // Add them together and display
  var sum =  my_input1 + my_input2 + my_input3 + my_input4 + my_input5 + my_input6;
  if(sum==100){
    alert('Sum is = 100');
    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
  }else if(sum<100){
    alert('Sum is less than 100');
    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
  }else if(sum>100){
    alert('Sum is bigger than 100');
    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input1" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input2" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input3" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input4" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input5" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input6" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
```

Here is the details about [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! @sanjayyadav

Comment: sumon@@can you help me count hundred number  if any field, like if i put 100 number in one input filed and other is null then the script is run . without alert message

Comment: Ahh !Ok , Wait... Updating my answer @sanjayyadav

Comment: It is already done in my answer. If you put `100` in any fields, the script will run without any alert message. @sanjayyadav

Comment: please check this this code is not working , please see this

Comment: This  code give only  laert message. help needed if  i feel hundred in  one input box it's proceed without alert message .

Comment: Click on `Run code snippet` button and test the answer, @sanjayyadav

Comment: yes I checking when I put 100 or 150 in one field its showing alert some is not equal to 100

Comment: Just update your condition like `if(sum<100)` OR `if(sum>100)` @sanjayyadav

Comment: You are most welcome! I updated answer with `if else`. So, you can set your alert or code in `if else` block. @sanjayyadav

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
    var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
    var my_input3 = document.getElementById('my_input3').value;
    var my_input4= document.getElementById('my_input4').value;
    var my_input5 = document.getElementById('my_input5').value;
    var my_input6 = document.getElementById('my_input6').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2) + parseInt(my_input3) + parseInt(my_input4) + parseInt(my_input5) + parseInt(my_input6);
    if(sum >= 100){
      document.write(sum);
    }
    else{
      alert("sum is less than 100")
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input1" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input2" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input3" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input4" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input5" /></br>
<input type="text" id="my_input6" />
<input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
```

Comment: @sanjayyadav does it helps?

Comment: well gaurav need some small change , if alert only it's below two 100 if equl or max to 100 then query will success

Comment: @sanjayyadav like this? that's a minor change you can do yourself too

Comment: Hello gaurav I want stop redirection after popup message closed can you help me regarding to this

Comment: @sanjayyadav this is not a coding site. Post a different question if you are having some problem. Your statements are not clear, there is no redirection here

Comment: Gaurav @@can you help me count hundred number  if any field, like if i put 100 number in one input filed and other is null then the script is run . without alert message

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understood what you want, you can try this:

```
var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2) + parseInt(my_input3) + parseInt(my_input4) + parseInt(my_input5) + parseInt(my_input6);

if (sum != 100) {
   alert('Different from a hundred')
   return false;
}
```

I used `return false` in case you want to handle the result and take some other action.

Comment: Ricardo Pontual@ I am using this , but i think  i have to control this  before submit this form

Comment: So you should use something like this:  `<input type="submit" onclick="return doMath()" />`

Comment: Ricardo @@can you help me count hundred number  if any field, like if i put 100 number in one input filed and other is null then the script is run . without alert message

Answer (score 0):

You can use alert() function to display alert popup

```
            if(sum!=100){
              alert("Sum is not equal to 100");
            }else{
              document.write(sum);
            }
```

Please refer working snippet

```js
      
            function doMath()
            {
                // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
                var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
                var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;
                 var my_input3 = document.getElementById('my_input3').value;
                var my_input4= document.getElementById('my_input4').value;
                var my_input5 = document.getElementById('my_input5').value;
                var my_input6 = document.getElementById('my_input6').value;

                // Add them together and display
                var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2) + parseInt(my_input3) + parseInt(my_input4) + parseInt(my_input5) + parseInt(my_input6);
                
                if(sum!=100){
                  alert("Sum is not equal to 100");
                }else{
                  document.write(sum);
                }
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_input1" /></br>
    <input type="text" id="my_input2" /></br>
    <input type="text" id="my_input3" /></br>
    <input type="text" id="my_input4" /></br>
        <input type="text" id="my_input5" /></br>
        <input type="text" id="my_input6" />
        <input type="button" value="Add Them Together" onclick="doMath();" />
```

Comment: Dhiraj @ this is awesome answer by you , Thanks Man ,

Comment: Dhiraj @@can you help me count hundred number  if any field, like if i put 100 number in one input filed and other is null then the script is run . without alert message

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    document.write(sum);
```

with

```
    if(sum==100) {
        document.write(sum);
    } else {
        alert("show your messaage");    
    }
```

Comment: Singh@ this is awesome answer by you , Thanks Man ,

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Bachcha @@can you help me count hundred number  if any field, like if i put 100 number in one input filed and other is null then the script is run . without alert message

Comment: @Sanjay Yadav you can do this by following the code of Sumon Sarker. Add the function `function _get(ID) { return document.getElementById(ID); }` and replace the line `var my_input1 = _get('my_input1').value ? parseInt(_get('my_input1').value) : 0;`

Comment: I hope this will help, Please let me know still you are facing issue.